# Why will my elseif statment never executed

Tags: c++

Any idea why the else if statment will be never executed ? The value of difference is constantly changing when the program runs.

```
        double difference = abs(reale_x[0] - reale_x[1]);
        if (0 <= difference < 45) {
            timer_counter += 1;
            if (timer_counter == 30) {
                cout << "CLICK" << '\n';
            }
        }
        else if (difference > 50) {
            timer_counter = 0;
        }
```

Comment: this doesn't do what you think it does: (0 <= difference < 45)

Comment: you want  (difference >= 0 && difference < 45)

Comment: First, above comment is correct. You are actually comparing the result of `0 <= difference` with 45 which is not what you actually want. `0 <= difference` will always be less than 45 because it will yield 1 or 0. And did you consider if the difference is between 45 and 50?

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue. Coming from python didn't expected it will work like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not how comparation works in c++.

What this code

```
if (0 <= difference < 45) {
```

does is it first compares if 0 is smaller or equal to `difference`. It is then "replaced" by a bool value either true or false. And then a bool value (so either 1 or 0) is compared to 45. And it will always be smaller than 45. What you have there is an always true statement.

So the way you would write this if statement is

```
if (difference >= 0 && difference < 45){
```

Note that because of your else if statement it will not execute if the difference is >44 and <51

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the issue. Coming from python didn't expected it will work like that.

Answer (score 2):

`if (0 <= difference < 45)`  will be executed as  `if ((0 <= difference) < 45)`,  which will be either `0<45` or `1<45` and will always be `true`. That's why the `else` part is not getting executed.

Answer (score 0):

in mathematics, we see and write `0 <= x < 45` or something like that to define the range of the variable `x`. But in order to tell the computer  the same thing, you have to  tell more clearly. Saying, to have to tell the compiler, that the value of x is greater than or equal to zero and at the same time, that value will be less than 45, and you can tell the compiler by this statement: `difference >= && difference < 45` . the `&&` is an 'AND' operator in most of the languages.